# Calling controller in Codeigniter via checkbox click

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox, controller

I need that when clicking on a checkbox, I sent it to a remote url to call a controller in Codeigniter This is what I'm trying to do...

```
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
   if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
           alert("go to url"); 
   } else { 
      alert("isnt active"); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a request to the url?

Comment: Yes, I want if checkbox is active, go to a url of the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use ajax to make the request to the server.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/controller-name/function-name/parameter1",
  cache: false
}).done(function(data) {
  //Do something with the response.
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
       $.ajax({
        url:base_url+'your_controller_name/your_function_name',
        type: 'post',
        data:{any data you want to sent},
        success : function(resp){
            if(resp)
            {
                //do what you want
            }
        },
        error : function(resp){}
       }); 
    } else { 
       alert("isnt active"); 
    } 
});
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

**UPDATE**

May be you want like this.

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) { 
        window.location.href="domain_name/your_controller_name/your_function_name"; 
    } else { 
        alert("isnt active"); 
    } 
});
```